# How do I know which USB device is my device?

Tags: raspbian, usb

I'm using two devices which are an USB to Serial converter and a GSM module. Both of them are shown as `/dev/ttyUSB`(`0` and `1`).

How can I determine which file descriptor (FD) is which USB device?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could set up some `udev` rules. There is some information [here.](http://www.reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html)

That way you can make sure your serial converter and GSM modules consistently mount to the same place.

Comment: well after GG the udev rules, I can map the device to an permanent FD. Thanks

Answer (score 9):

As hinted, you may find information using `lsusb`. However — assuming you don't know how plug and play works on USB — the "why" `lsusb` is that *every* removable device, that you plug into the USB connector, signals to the system (amongst other information) **identifiers** for the **vendor** and **product**, respectively `idVendor` and `idProduct`, both of which you can see in `lsusb` output.

Another way is to check the system log, which provides more verbose information:

```
Apr 19 11:20:05 my_machine kernel: [1768201.806503] usb 3-3: new full-speed USB device number 72 using xhci_hcd
Apr 19 11:20:05 my_machine kernel: [1768201.823169] usb 3-3: New USB device found, idVendor=067b, idProduct=2303
Apr 19 11:20:05 my_machine kernel: [1768201.823179] usb 3-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
Apr 19 11:20:05 my_machine kernel: [1768201.823185] usb 3-3: Product: USB-Serial Controller D
Apr 19 11:20:05 my_machine kernel: [1768201.823191] usb 3-3: Manufacturer: Prolific Technology Inc. 
Apr 19 11:20:05 my_machine kernel: [1768201.824118] pl2303 3-3:1.0: pl2303 converter detected
Apr 19 11:20:05 my_machine kernel: [1768201.825628] usb 3-3: pl2303 converter now attached to ttyUSB0
Apr 19 11:20:05 my_machine mtp-probe: checking bus 3, device 72: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-3"
```

In this log excerpt you will see the VendorID and ProductID of a Serial-on-USB controller, which uses a chip, a *PL2303* (`pl2303`), from a company named "`Prolific Technology Inc.`".

By looking at these lines you will know what device you plugged in (e.g. `idVendor=067b, idProduct=2303`), when (`Apr 19 11:20:05`) and what device node the device (`ttyUSB0`) can be accessed through. You'll also get the full system path to the device, namely `/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-3`.

On a Debian machine, or on a Raspberry Pi installed with Raspbian, the system log file is `/var/log/syslog`.

Answer (score 3):

Use `lsusb`. This should give you the data that you require and enable you to determine which FD points to which device.

> `lsusb` is a utility for displaying information about USB buses in the system and the devices connected to them.

See [man page](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/lsusb8.html) or type `man lsusb` in a terminal.

Answer (score 0):

I've come up with my own script to do this in a much handier, more useful way for me,

```
#!/bin/bash

function exit_no_firmware {
    exit 0
}

device=$1
echo "Checking ${device}"
usb_device_path=$(realpath /sys/class/tty/$(readlink /sys/class/tty/$(basename ${device}))/../../../../)

if [ ! -f "${usb_device_path}/idProduct" ]; then
    echo "The selected serial port is not a USB device."
    exit 0
fi

if [ ! -f "${usb_device_path}/manufacturer" ] || [ ! -f "${usb_device_path}/product" ]; then
    echo "USB device is missing manufacturer or product name."
    exit 0
fi

usb_manufacturer=$(cat "${usb_device_path}/manufacturer")
usb_product=$(cat "${usb_device_path}/product")

echo "Identified as ${usb_product} from ${usb_manufacturer}."
```

Usage

```
$ identify.sh /dev/ttyUSB0
Checking /dev/ttyUSB0
Identified as SkyConnect v1.0 from Nabu Casa.
```

I came up with this after looking into how Home Assistant ensure it's flashing the right device, all credit to them and agners who is down as the author of the file - https://github.com/home-assistant/addons/blob/master/openthread_border_router/rootfs/etc/s6-overlay/scripts/universal-silabs-flasher-up